# Change jQuery version with hook_form_alter

Tags: hooks, javascript, forms

How do I change the jQuery version used for a form with a specific form ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you would like to achieve is loading another version of jQery in your form page. You need to understand the way hook system works. `hook_js_alter()` is defined as:

> "Perform necessary alterations to the JavaScript before it is
>   presented on the page."

You can use the above hook to change jQuery version. `hook_form_alter()` is defined as:

> Perform alterations before a form is rendered.

So, first action is `hook_js_alter()` and second action is `hook_form_alter()`. You cannot change jQuery version with the second hook, but you can use the following code.

```
function mymodule_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  if ($_GET['q'] == "node/add/page") {
     // Swap out jQuery to use an updated version of the library.
  $javascript['misc/jquery.js']['data'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'jquery_update') . '/jquery.js';
  }
}
```

For more information on [using newer versions of jQuery](https://drupal.org/node/1058168) you can refer the Drupal.org article which explains how to add Newer versions selectively using various methods.

Comment: i did something like so 

  if($_GET['q']=='node/add/data-definition'){
 $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'equations') . '/js/jquery.1.7.2.min.js';
 $js[$path] = $js['misc/jquery.js'];
 $js[$path]['data'] = $path;
 unset($js['misc/jquery.js']);
 unset($js['misc/ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js']);
 }
and it worked well